# Unable to debug using Developer Tools - Inspect option in MAC OS - chrome Browser Extension

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, devtools

I open the developer tools and when I click the drop-down to select the context, it only shows the website open(TOP) and ad-block extension. I don't see my extension.

I can get to it by clicking on "inspect" popup option, but it opens it in a new window and I don't see the option to dock it to the browser.

Comment: Do you have a content script?

Comment: I have background script but no content script.

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to access?

Comment: Chrome Version 44.0.2403.125 (64-bit) on Mac OS 10.10.4 - Does not work , Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704557/chrome-developer-tools-console-will-not-display?rq=1